# Wouldn't Matt Smith actually be the 12th Doctor because of the War Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

If you think about it, the show didn't really talk much about the Doctor who fought in the Time War, so wouldn't Matt Smith technically be the 12th doctor and Peter Capaldi the 13th?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wouldn't Matt Smith be the 12th Doctor and not the 11th because David Tennant is both 10 and 11?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202311/wouldnt-matt-smith-be-the-12th-doctor-and-not-the-11th-because-david-tennant-is)

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Unless I'm missing something obvious that question appears to be about a different situation that might make the numbering off.

Comment: Yes, quite, that's why the numbering is moot anyhow. This question may be based on a shaky assumption about the numbers in the first place. @TheLethalCarrot

Comment: Jo Martin playing an [incarnation of the doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugitive_Doctor) from an unspecified time in the far past adds another inconvenience to the calculation of the numbering. @TheLethalCarrot

Comment: There's now an unlimited number given that The Doctor is "The Timeless Child"

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, but he calls himself the Eleventh.

In-universe, the War Doctor wasn't technically a Doctor - he's "the one who broke the promise", and subsequent incarnations (at least the first few who don't remember the true end of the Time War) are ashamed of him and don't want to remember him. So they keep the numbering of Doctors without acknowledging him. This is mentioned explicitly in "The Time of the Doctor", as well as the Meta-Crisis regeneration that allowed two David Tennant Doctors:

> CLARA: But you don't die. You change. You pop right back up with a new face.
> DOCTOR: No, not for ever. I can change twelve times. Thirteen versions of me. Thirteen silly Doctors.
> **CLARA: Okay, so you're number eleven, so
>
> DOCTOR: Ha. Are we forgetting Captain Grumpy, eh? I didn't call myself the Doctor during the Time War, but it was still a regeneration.
>
> CLARA: Okay, so you're number twelve.**
> DOCTOR: Well, number ten once regenerated and kept the same face. I had vanity issues at the time. Twelve regenerations, Clara. I can't ever do it again.

That's why the Matt Smith Doctor was all out of regenerations at the end of his life, even though he's only called the Eleventh Doctor and Time Lords are supposed to have thirteen faces.

Out of universe, of course, the explanation is that nobody had thought of the War Doctor by the time the Ninth and Tenth Doctors were getting their numbers, so they had to retcon him into the timeline without forcing everyone to start calling the Christopher Eccleston Doctor the "tenth" and the David Tennant Doctor the "eleventh". Probably the reason the aborted Meta-Crisis regeneration actually counts for the purposes of the regeneration limit (unlike, say, the Twelfth Doctor's aborted regeneration in the third Monks episode of Series 10) is that Steven Moffat wanted to be the one who wrote around the thirteen-face limit and opened everything up for the Doctor to go on regenerating as long as necessary.

Comment: In my head canon for the War Doctor - the way to reconcile the age of Doctor in classic era to 9 being 900 is he restarted at zero when he died as 8 just to distinguish that he was no longer the same.  Really I think he was too hard on himself though wiping put Gallifrey certainly justified his depression at reversing 8s pacifist policy.

Comment: Except Moffat wasn't the one to write around the limit because the Doctor had been given extra regenerations in the past during the original run of classic Who in the 60s.

Answer (score 0):

'Out-of-universe', Matt Smith was cast as the eleventh Doctor - the eleventh actor to play an incarnation of the character in the TV series, in sequence. The fact that his first episode was titled 'Eleventh Hour' demonstrates that. Moffatt has spoken about the fact that he originally hoped to convince Christopher Eccleston to appear in the 50th anniversary special as the Ninth Doctor, and the 'War Doctor' was only conceived to fill his space. So, the whole concept of there being a previously unseen incarnation of The Doctor was likely created *after* Matt had been styled as the eleventh.

In-universe, it's not that the Doctor called *himself* the 'Eleventh' - he just calls himself "the Doctor". The Doctor rarely mentions their regeneration number, some exceptions prior to the War Doctor's existence being the first Doctor declaring on various occasions that he was "the original", the Eighth Doctor recounting that he was "nearing the end of his seventh life".

But, after the War Doctor, Eleven revealed to Craig through a vision that he was "eleventh", so he did consider himself to be the Eleventh 'Doctor'. The Doctor denied his incarnation as 'the War Doctor' because he didn't live up to the name he chose for himself, being a warrior rather than a healer, and this is evidently why he discounted this incarnation numerically. However, the Time Lords still recognised the War Doctor as The Doctor - at the end of 'The Day of the Doctor', when all his incarnations up to and including Twelve (Capaldi) circled the planet the Time Lords counted "all thirteen!"

The important factor is that the incarnation we call 'Eleven' was *perceived by others to be the eleventh*. The Silence were trying to end the Doctor's life by terminating his eleventh incarnation - you may recall Dorium referred to 'the fall of the eleventh'. This is significant because the Doctor showed that how he is *perceived* is what matters. The Silence would have continued hunting him down until they believed Eleven was dead. They surely knew that, as a time-traveller, he would still appear throughout time and space in his various incarnations, but they were satisfied that his life came to an end before the question of his identity was answered. So, by making them *think* that he died, he stopped them from further hunting him. By the same reasoning, it didn't really matter that he was not actually the eleventh incarnation - the Silence's prophecies concerned the fall of the eleventh, they believed that to be him, and they believed that they killed him.

Additionally, the current storyline (season 12/13) involves at least 1 (but possibly more) previously unknown incarnations of The Doctor that we did not know about (and that The Doctor had been made to forget about). This would mean that, numerically speaking, Matt Smith may have been the 13th, or higher!

Comment: " I can't think of any occasion The Doctor ever referred to his number,"   he did in 'The Lodger' he shows Craig a montage of his past, then says "eleventh".